# PHP - Generate PDF by retrieving pages from database

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, fpdf, html2canvas

I am generating some pages with some styling by retrieving page specific data from the database. I want to convert it all into one PDF, page after page. Is there any way I can take such PDF snapshots, just like html2canvas?

Comment: "Save the snapshot of a div in PDF" sounds ugly, you are converting your html (or your div ) in a pdf

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your html(with  data) as you want in pdf & than convert it in pdf.
Although there are many solutions you can google it, I recommend the following two:

[HTM2PDF](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/) - offers an API to convert HTML to PDF and also has a PHP SDK, which makes 
it very easy to implement in PHP; It offers a choice of server locations in Europe, Asia and the USA

[PDFmyURL](http://pdfmyurl.com/) - offers an API that does URL and HTML to PDF as well, with roughly the 
same functionality as HTM2PDF, but works on a load balanced landscape and has been around a little longer

Comment: All the data is being retrieved from database. Also, there is lot of styling used. I want a snapshot kind of thing. Also, I need to run a complete loop by generating different kinds of pages for different index and keep adding pages to the PDF. Will it serve my purpose?

Comment: no problem generate your html  with data and style first than after covert your prepared html in pdf.

Comment: And how to loop through pages and make sure they keep getting added in the same PDF?

Comment: had you try something ?